# Segmentation fault when trying to remove an element from an dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, function, for-loop, dynamic

I am trying to remove an element from an dynamic array of structs by moving each struct to the left then reallocating my array one size smaller.

**My question is:** what is the difference between `*(p[i])=*(p[i]+1);` and `(*p)[i]=(*p)[i+1];`, and why does the second one works whilst the first code does not, resulting in segmentation fault.

```
void rm_event(struct events **p, int index, int qtty){
    for(int i=index; i<qtty-1; i++){
        *(p[i])=*(p[i]+1); // (*p)[i]=(*p)[i+1];
    }

    struct events *tmp;
    tmp=(struct events*)realloc(*p, sizeof(struct events)*(qtty-1));
    if(tmp!=NULL)
        *p=tmp;
}
```

Comment: `*(p[i])` dereferences the address of `p` with offset `i` (which is memory outside of `p`), whilst `(*p)[i]` dereferences `p` and then offsets it with `i`. Filling in some random numbers, let's say `p` on address 10 points to address 30, and `i` is 5, `*(p[i])` would give `*(10+5)` = `*15`, and `(*p)[i]` gives `(*10)+5` which gives `30 + 5` = `35`: two completely different addresses.

Comment: The expression `*(p[i])` is the same as `p[i][0]`. And if `p` doesn't point to an array then you will go out of bounds. And `*(p[i]+1)` is the same as `p[i][1]`.

Comment: `struct events **p,` can be used in a couple of ways - ambiguous without additional information. It could be 1)  pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to a struct events, 2) pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to the first element of an array of struct events, or 3) pointer to a pointer to the first element of an array of struct events. Commonly, and in this case, it is #3. In the different cases, different patterns of dereferencing are correct vs. undefined behavior. Compiler can't tell, you have to get the right syntax for the semantics you are using.

Comment: Instead of mucking with trying to copy structs one-by-one, look into `memmove()` to replace the intricate `for()` body... The work has been done for you.

Answer (score 1):

As `struct **p` the expression `(*p)[i]` first references `(*p)` which is a `(struct event *)` at the start of you array and `[i]` dereference index `i`:

```
(*p): (struct events *) 0x5555555592a0
(*p)[1]: (struct events *) 0x5555555592a4
```

In contrast `*(p[i])` will deference whatever is stored `i * sizeof(struct events**)` bytes after `p` then deference that again with `*(...)`.  Either dereference may trigger a segfault:

```
p: (struct events **) 0x7fffffffde68
p+1: (struct events **) 0x7fffffffde70
p[1]: (struct events **) 0x7fffffffdf70
```

These addresses are from the same run, btw,  `*p` is the address of the memory returned from the heap via `malloc()` while `p` is address on the stack where the argument is being passed.

Here's the memmove implementation, btw, and you should report an error back to caller otherwise they don't know the correct size of the array.  Also moved the `len` argument first to express how `p` and `len` are related:

```
void rm_event(size_t len, struct events *p[len], size_t index) {
    if(!p || *p || index >= len || !len)
        return;

    memmove(&(*p)[index], &(*p)[index+1], (len - index - 1) * sizeof **p);

    struct events *tmp;
    tmp = realloc(*p, sizeof(struct events)*(len - 1));
    if(!tmp)
        return;
    *p=tmp;
}
```